# SVG toolbar icons in VS Code extension

Tags: svg, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The documentation says you can't reference SVG from markdown, but I didn't see anything saying I couldn't use it for toolbar icons. I've done just that, and an icon that works perfectly in the extension host is missing when I package and install from a VSIX.

Is SVG also disallowed for toolbar icons within an extension? If I must render bitmaps, in what format and at what resolutions? Is there detailed guidance on this that I have failed to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG is supported.

Files in `project-root/src` are not bundled. Put the icons anywhere other than the `src` folder and they will be bundled. (I certainly snatched defeat from the jaws of victory with *that* one!)